# How to run multiple functions in python using multithreading?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am newbie to python world and trying my hand in multi-threading and multiprocessing. I have two functions and want to run them in parallel and want to utilize maximum available.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def func1(name='1'):
    print("function, %s" % name)
    for i in range(1,100000000):
        x=i*i

def func2(name='2'):
    print("function, %s" % name)
    for j in range(1,100000000):
        y=j*j

def func3(name='3'):
    print("function, %s" % name)
    for i in range(1,100000000):
        x=i*i

def func4(name='4'):
    print("function, %s" % name)
    for j in range(1,100000000):
        y=j*j


p1 = Process(target=func1)
p1.start()
p2 = Process(target=func2)
p2.start()
p3 = Process(target=func3)
p3.start()
p4 = Process(target=func4)
p4.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()
p4.join()
```

How can both process use maximum available cores?

Comment: Wouldn't it generally be useful for the thread/process to actually need to do some work?

Comment: Your example doesn't make any sense as it will use a max of two cores. Was your example was meant to suggest there could be a large number of `Process()` calls? Or that the two functions are each able to do many things in parallel? Basically, your question is insufficiently precise for any useful advice.

Comment: I have edited my question to do some useful calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) which allows you to set a max_workers parameter for the number of processors you want to use.